# share Form or Container with Codename One

Tags: java, share, codenameone

I wan t to share my app screen on CN1, the idea is createan screensgot as JPG and the share it.

From other post I have this code

```
 @Override
protected void onGpsTracker_Button1Action(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

  String file="toShare.jpeg";
  String path="";
    Image i= Image.createImage(c.getComponentForm().getWidth(),c.getComponentForm().getHeight());
  c.paintComponent(i.getGraphics());
  OutputStream save;
    try {
        save = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(file);
        ImageIO.getImageIO().save(i, save, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG,(float) 0.90f);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
          String [] entries= Storage.getInstance().listEntries();
   for( int k=0;k< entries.length;k++){

      if (entries[k].startsWith("toShare")){
        path=(String)Storage.getInstance().readObject(entries[k]);}}
   findShareSec().setImageToShare(path, "image/jpeg"); 


}
```

I cannot find the method of the last line

```
findShareSec()
```

so the image is not saved.
Once the image is saved, how I share it??
on Android Studio I use shareIntent and is shared on every app instaled

Answer (score 3):

We just added [this exact sample to the ShareButton](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/ShareButton.html) before the weekend!

```
Form hi = new Form("ShareButton");
ShareButton sb = new ShareButton();
sb.setText("Share Screenshot");
hi.add(sb);

Image screenshot = Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(), hi.getHeight());
hi.revalidate();
hi.setVisible(true);
hi.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);

String imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "screenshot.png";
try(OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile)) {
    ImageIO.getImageIO().save(screenshot, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
}
sb.setImageToShare(imageFile, "image/png");
```

Here is the Java 5 version of the code above:

```
Form hi = new Form("ShareButton");
ShareButton sb = new ShareButton();
sb.setText("Share Screenshot");
hi.add(sb);

Image screenshot = Image.createImage(hi.getWidth(), hi.getHeight());
hi.revalidate();
hi.setVisible(true);
hi.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);

String imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "screenshot.png";
try {
    OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile);
    ImageIO.getImageIO().save(screenshot, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
    Util.cleanup(os);
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(err);
}
```

Comment: I receive this message

Comment: error: try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
try(OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile)) {
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)

Comment: If you have an older Java 5 project you need to modify it to make it use Java 8 syntax otherwise build will fail locally and in the build servers. I edited the code above to use standard Java 5 code. You can migrate to the new Java 8 syntax by following the instructions here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/java-8-support.html